# Asynchronous TCP socket bytes merging

Tags: c#, .net

I wasn't quite sure how to explain my problem in the title, but I'll try to elaborate on my problem.

Basically I'm coding a chat that is not P2P, but where all users connect to a central server, similar to IRC. The connections are asynchronous and it almost works flawlessly. The main issue is that, when a lot of data is sent to one user (or to the server from one user) at once, the bytes may merge, resulting in errors. I've approached this by adding a header of 4 bytes containing the length of the data in front of the rest of the data. Still, the bytes seem to merge. I've also tried setting **NoDelay** to **true** and **DontFragment** to **false**; still, it doesn't work.

I'm guessing the problem is that when the bytes merge, I only handle the first bytes and then do nothing with the remaining. What would be the best way to approach this issue?

Receive callback code: http://pastebin.com/f0MvjHag

Comment: `What would be the best way to approach this issue?`  showing us your code would help a lot.

Comment: @orzechowskid Of course. Added link to the receive callback source in op.

Comment: on SO it is customary to add code to the question, not to link to it. If the code is too long, work it down to a short self-contained example of the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's why they call it a stream.  You put bytes in at one end and TCP guarantees they come out in the same order, none missing or duplicated, at the far end.  Anything bigger than a byte is your problem.

You have to accumulate enough bytes in a buffer to have your header.  Then interpret it and start processing additional bytes.  You may have a few left over that start the next header.

This is normal behavior.  When your application is not receiving data the system will be buffering it for you.  It will try to hand off the available data the next time you make a request.  On the other side, a large write may travel over connections that do not support an adequate frame size.  They will be split as needed and arrive eventually in dribs and drabs.

Comment: So the best solution would be something like this: Read a buffer, get the length of the data, check if data length + 4 = read length, and if read length > data length + 4 handle the rest of the buffer? Not sure if I made myself clear.

Comment: A state machine makes this easier as you alternate between handling headers and bodies.  Keep appending received data to a buffer.  Each time a read completes: If buffer length >= header length then process header.  If remaining buffer length >= message body length then process message.  And check to see if you already have the next header ... .  (Lather, rinse, repeat.)

Comment: Before trying your suggestion, I tried a different approach. First, I read 4 bytes asynchronously, obviously containing the length of the data. Then, I do a loop that reads until all data has been received. I write all the data into a stream and handle it after data has been received. Then, it repeats and reads the 4 bytes again. What do you think about this approach?

Comment: The issues that need to be handled are: (1) The initial read must not complete prior to receiving 4 bytes.  (2) When you read the message body you must either ensure that the last read ends where the message ends, or buffer any additional bytes that arrive.  The API you pick may limit your choices.  As for completing reassembly of the message only to put it into another stream, that's more overhead than I would have chosen.  And a stream is just bytes that ... .  At least a `MemoryStream` should behave more consistently than a TCP socket.

Comment: Well, the approach I described _seems_ to be working flawlessly at the moment, but I'll get back to this thread if it doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

This usually happens when two or more packets of data are sent at close intervals.
I recently had this problem myself, and the way I resolved it was to a separating key. You can then tokenize each message. For example, you could add the ASCII character #4 (the End-of-Transmission character) to the end of each message being sent like I did.

```
Write("Message1" + ((char)4).ToString())
Write("Message2" + ((char)4).ToString())
```

Then, when the client receives the data, you can iterate through the received data. When it finds that special character, it knows it's the end of one message, and (maybe) the beginning of a new one.

```
"Message1(EOT char)Message2(EOT char)"
```

`\n` may be easier to work with than using ASCII characters.

Comment: While this is a valid (and fairly common) technique, it has problems when you EOT character can show up in your stream. If that can happen, you need to escape the EOT character and the escape character.

Comment: Yeah the one I wrote escapes it. Probably should've mentioned that, quite an important point, even though the EOT char is quite rare in common use (at least, in my usage).