# TCPListener for multiple ports

Tags: .net, multithreading, sockets, tcplistener

I need some pointers (worked examples would be wonderful) on the following problem. I'm new to socket programming, although not to .net, dont mind if any help is in VB or c#.

I have a 'client' system, which will spit out regular chunks of data (its actually ascii) every few (lets say 10) seconds. The data will be of a small size, probably less than 1K, and I can have each output delimited by a specific sequence (say `<EoM>`). This 'client' will output to several (more than 1, less than 5) different ports.

I need to write a server, which will open the required number of ports, listen on them for data arriving. When a message has arrived on one of the ports, with the `<EoM>` delimiter at the end, I want to be able to take that data and go off and do some processing on it (parsing it and entering into a DB for info). and continue to listen for the next piece of data to arrive. This needs to be happening for all the ports defined. If the client should disconnect, I would prefer the ports to be able to wait and listen for a reconnect, and then continue processing as before. But as its a single client that will be communicating, I would be ok assuming that if 1 port is disconnected, it is ok to restart the server process if thats easier than listening again after a disconnect.

Sorry for the long and not terribly precise question, like I said, am new to socket programming, so any actual examples of how to do this would be much appreciated. The end result would ideally be a windows service, but I want to start it as a forms app until I've got it all working for ease of debugging.

Cheers for any help.

Comment: What you ask for is not what you want <g>.  All the clients should connect to the same server port and, if a disconnection occurs, the client end should do the reconnecting.  There should be no need for any process restarts - that would be somewhat inconvenient for a service process :)

Comment: TCP/IP doesn't handle messages, just a stream of bytes.  Do expect to reassemble your "chunks of data" from arbitrary dribs and drabs.  [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11804131/asynchronous-tcp-socket-bytes-merging/11804312#11804312) may help.

Comment: Typically an application listens on a port for a connect request.  When the request is received, another port is opened for communication with the new client.  The original port can continue to listen for additional connect requests.  Depending on your application you may want to listen on a single port number and accept multiple connections from your clients.  Each client can identify itself after connecting.  Your application would manage any issues regarding duplicate or missing clients relative to the set you expect.

Comment: There is only 1 client, and it outputs data to different ports. This part I cant change. Exactly what the processing of the data will be depends on the port it arrives on, hence the need to manage multiple ports. Any disconnect would be due to an error on the client side, and when it restarts, it would start transmitting data again to the same ports on the server.

Comment: Ah, overloading issues.  "Client" and "server" seem to refer to both ends of the connection simultaneously.  Traditionally, a TCP server listens for connections.  In this case one "producer" feeds data to several "consumers".  You have chosen to make the producer a TCP client and the consumers TCP servers.  Or am I still spinning?

Comment: @HABO Yes, I think its probably just my wording. In this case, the 'client' is actually a server outputting virtual wallboard data over the network. My 'Server' has to listen on the specific ports that the 'client' is outputting to, capture that data (every 10 secs or so) and process it. I have a very quick app built that sets up 2 sockets, and gets a networkstream from them, and echoes that to the console, so that I can see I can get data on 2 ports. But its just running a continuous loop on both socket threads, which doesnt seem ideal, and although the data is arriving correctly, I'm not

Comment: Sure how to just capture and process each 'message' I understand that tcp/ip doesnt deal in messages, but am kinda stuck how to go further. Also, if the 'client' disconnects, currently the sockets just get shut down, rather than waiting for a reconnect.

Comment: From the sounds of this, if I were you, I wouldn't waste my time with TCP, use UDP instead.  It's much easier to use and perfect for small chunks of data.  However, UDP gives no confirmation that the data arrived at the destination, so if it's important data, you can code your own confirmation code which gets returned to the client.  I've done this before and found it much faster and easier to code, especially when multithreading many listeners.

Answer (score 1):

A [TCPListener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) listens on only one port at a time. If you want to listen on multiple ports, you will need to create that many instances of TCPListener.

Since you want the listener on each port to perform different operations, you will need to accept a client on each port, and process the data you receive there.

The link above provides a basic beginners example on how to accept clients and listen for data. Although the async methods perform much better, this sync code is simpler and will get you started easily.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a TAP/TUN driver to install your own network interface (both Windows and Linux), giving you access down to raw ethernet frames. That way you can perform your own filtering on frames, find the relevant IP(s) and ports and forward to your own TCP/IP software stack for servicing.

Although this would work, there are disadvantages:

1. TAP/TUN drivers tend to be 10Mbps
2. User Mode processing of lower level packets is CPU intensive and packets are sometimes dropped
3. Having to build or use a TCP/IP library to digest frames into TCP protocol, including maintaining TCP session state.

TAP/TUN is great for security screening and perhaps UDP feats, but TCP/IP is another level.

Although this is a viable answer, I would recommend @nunespascal's answer. Async programming isn't that hard, and if you're only talking ~5 listeners that's reasonable. Even hundreds of dormant async listeners should be reasonable.