# Sending C structs through TCP in C#

Tags: c#, c, tcp, memcpy

I am writing a program to interact with the management interface for a piece of equipment over TCP.  The problem is, the documentation for the equipment is written in C, while the program I am writing is in C#.  My problem is, the documentation specifies

> The communication is based upon the C structure-based API buffer

No amount of Googling can seem to point me to this API or how I send a raw structure across TCP.  The documentation seems to imply that I should use memcpy to copy the struct to the TCP buffer, but C# doesn't directly support memcpy.  Is there an equivelant method in C# or a different way to accomplish this

Comment: You are about to meet up with the ugliness of streams.  There are some tips [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11804131/asynchronous-tcp-socket-bytes-merging).

Comment: This question is a perfect illustration of why the network protocol should never have been based on C structs in the first place. Protocol designers please take note.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could build a .Net version of your C struct, then use marshalling to send a byte array through the network. Here's an example with the `MLocation` C struct.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 8)]
public struct MLocation
{
    public int x;
    public int y;
};

public static void Main()
{
    MLocation test = new MLocation();

    // Gets size of struct in bytes
    int structureSize = Marshal.SizeOf(test);

    // Builds byte array
    byte[] byteArray = new byte[structureSize];

    IntPtr memPtr = IntPtr.Zero;

    try
    {
        // Allocate some unmanaged memory
        memPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(structureSize);

        // Copy struct to unmanaged memory
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(test, memPtr, true);

        // Copies to byte array
        Marshal.Copy(memPtr, byteArray, 0, structureSize);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (memPtr != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(memPtr);
        }
    }

    // Now you can send your byte array through TCP
    using (TcpClient client = new TcpClient("host", 8080))
    {
        using (NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream())
        {
            stream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        }
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Why do you have to use the unmanaged memory in order to copy to the bytearray? Isn't possible copy to the bytearray directly? 
I guess is something with how C# works but explanation will be good..

Answer (score 0):

You will use either unsafe structs,the BitConverter or write a managed C++ wrapper to fill the API buffer.
Essentially you are doing P/Invoke with calling a socket instead of calling a function.