# Receiving structs through TCP c#

Tags: c#, c, tcp, struct

This post is directly related to an earlier post I made

[Sending C structs through TCP in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11954431/sending-c-structs-through-tcp-in-c-sharp)

My next problem is receiving the appropriate response from the equipment.  The documentation gives me the following code for the returned struct.

```
typedef struct{
/*This value represents if the API request to modify has been a success or not*/
return_t ret_val;

/*Error code indicating error details*/
error_t err_code;

/*Response object for GET type action*/
U8 payload[0];
}MsgResp;
```

My question is, how do I get the raw byte stream received over TCP into this struct? Again, my instinct tell me something to do with memcpy, but I don't know how this translates to C#.

I am also confused about the types return_t and error_t, so any insight into those would also be helpful.

Comment: Hint: look for `typedef XXX return_t;` in the same or included C header file. `XXX` would be the underlying data type. Same for `error_t`.

Comment: @SLaks, ah I missed it. removed my comment

Answer (score 0):

The link from SLaks comment above is exactly what I needed.

Link here: [How To Convert Structure to byte array in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3278827/how-to-convert-structure-to-byte-array-in-c)